# HTML Styling a user row

Tags: html, css

I have a few problems, when I try to style a row that I designed. Here is how the row should look like:
[image]

Now I am pretty far, but the content of a row is all below eachother. I already changed to a CSS Grid, but thats why I got this problem!

Here is the snippet of my current code:

```css
.user-part {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.user-part .list {
    width: 100%;
}

.user-part .list .seperation-line {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #C4C4C4;
    height: 2px;
    padding: 0px;
}


.user-part .list .list-header {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.user-part .list .list-header .grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 5% auto auto auto auto 10% auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.user-part .list .list-header .grid-container > div {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.user-part .list .list-user {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.user-part .list .list-user span {
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 100%;
}

/*---Toggle switch---*/
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input { 
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.switch .slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.switch .slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.switch input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #48CE19;
}

.switch input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #48CE19;
}

.switch input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

.switch .slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.switch .slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
/*--------------------*/
```

```html
<div class="user-part">
    <div class="list">
        <div class="list-header">
            <div class="grid-container">
                <div>
                    <span>Id</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span>Naam</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span>Email</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span>Laatste login</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span>Gerapporteerd</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span>Actief</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="seperation-line"></div>
        
        <div class="list-user">
            <div class="grid-container">
                <div>
                    <span>266</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span>Alexander Vreeswijk</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span>alexander@vreeswijk.eu</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span>2020-10-05 16:22</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span>0</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label class="switch">
                        <input type="checkbox" checked>
                        <span class="slider round"></span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href=""><img src="images/EditUser.png" /></a>
                    <a href=""><img src="images/DeleteUser.png" /></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="seperation-line"></div>
        
    </div>
</div>
```

The content of a row is all below eachtother, how can I fix that?

Comment: the problem ehre and on smalelr screens is simply the viewport width. Havy you tryied to achieve this this with a css grind instead of flexboxes yet. For that case I think using a grid is the better method.

Comment: You mean <table> then right? I am not an css expert, I am trying to practise!

Comment: no it is pretty much something like a table with more advantages and simplier to use: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp - along with flexboxes it is the modernw ay to go and definitly important do learn. For cases where you want a table layout or align items on a self defined grid, the css grid is the way to go.

Comment: I updated my question. The whole thing is now a CSS Grid, but the content of a row is all below each other

Comment: I don't think saying *"whole thing now is a CSS Grid"* while adding a single `display: grid` line and keeping `position: absolute` and `position: relative` on other things counts as a worthwhile edit.

Comment: To begin with, you should apply `width: 100%` to `.user-part .list .list-header` to make it span the whole parent width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Live example with some adjusts on your code:

```css
.user-part {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.user-part .list {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.list-user {
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 42px;
}

.user-part .list .seperation-line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #C4C4C4;
}

.user-part .list .list-header {
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.user-part .list .list-header span {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.user-part .list .list-header .header-id {
  width: 8%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.user-part .list .list-header .header-name {
  width: 16%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.user-part .list .list-header .header-email {
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.user-part .list .list-header .header-lastlogin {
  width: 13%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.user-part .list .list-header .header-reported {
  width: 13%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.user-part .list .list-header .header-active {
  width: 13%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.user-part .list .list-header .header-buttons {
  width: 13%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.user-part .list .list-user {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.user-part .list .list-user span {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.user-part .list .list-user .user-id {
  width: 8%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.user-part .list .list-user .user-name {
  width: 16%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.user-part .list .list-user .user-email {
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.user-part .list .list-user .user-lastlogin {
  width: 13%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.user-part .list .list-user .user-reported {
  width: 13%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.user-part .list .list-user .user-active {
  width: 13%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.user-part .list .list-user .user-buttons {
  width: 13%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.user-part .list .list-user .user-buttons a {
  padding: 5px;
}


/*---Toggle switch---*/

.user-part .list .list-user .user-active .switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.user-part .list .list-user .user-active .switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.user-part .list .list-user .user-active .switch .slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.user-part .list .list-user .user-active .switch .slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.user-part .list .list-user .user-active .switch input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

.user-part .list .list-user .user-active .switch input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

.user-part .list .list-user .user-active .switch input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

.user-part .list .list-user .user-active .switch .slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.user-part .list .list-user .user-active .switch .slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="user-part">

  <div class="list">

    <div class="list-header">
      <div class="header-id"><span>Id</span></div>
      <div class="header-name"><span>Naam</span></div>
      <div class="header-email"><span>Email</span></div>
      <div class="header-lastlogin"><span>Laatste login</span></div>
      <div class="header-reported"><span>Gerapporteerd</span></div>
      <div class="header-active"><span>Actief</span></div>
      <div class="header-buttons"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="seperation-line"></div>

    <div class="list-user">

      <div class="user-id">
        <span>266</span>
      </div>

      <div class="user-name">
        <span>Alexander Vreeswijk</span>
      </div>

      <div class="user-email">
        <span>alexander@vreeswijk.eu</span>
      </div>

      <div class="user-lastlogin">
        <span>2020-10-05 16:22</span>
      </div>

      <div class="user-reported">
        <span>0</span>
      </div>

      <div class="user-active">
        <label class="switch">
          <input type="checkbox" checked>
          <span class="slider round"></span>
        </label>
      </div>

      <div class="user-buttons">
        <a href=""><img src="images/EditUser.png" /></a>
        <a href=""><img src="images/DeleteUser.png" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="seperation-line"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but 1 final question about this code: How can I allign the imagebuttons and the toggle switch with the text vertically?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk, adding a line-height (bigger than toggle) to your list-user will align it automaticaly. I updated de answer.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to put the image buttons in the same line by changing `.user-buttons` and `.user-buttons` a classes, see them below

```css
.user-part .list .list-user .user-buttons {
  display: inline-block;
}

.user-part .list .list-user .user-buttons a {
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but I updated my code based on the reaction of @tacoshy. I am using a CSS Grid now. See my code above!